# Do I have to return `NULL` for thread function when I use the detached pthread in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

For example:

```
void* thread(void *arg)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t th;
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(pthread_attr_t &attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_create(&th, &attr, thread, NULL);
}
```

Because of it's a detached thread, I can not receive the funtion retrun by `pthread_join`. So I think the return of thread is useless, should I return `NULL`? If I don't return `NULL`, will it cause some bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I return NULL?

You can return `nullptr` or any other value whether the thread is detached or not.

> If I don't return NULL, will it cause some bug?

If you don't return anything then the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

P.S. The C++ standard library has portable wrappers for threads which allow you to not depend on any particular operating system. I recommend using those instead of system specific API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! ^_^ I will consider use C++ standard library(in fact, my program only run in linux, so I didn't consider about cross-platform). So dose undefined behaviour mean dangerous because of the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @0811张庆昊 Undefined behaviour means that there are no restrictions for the behaviour. Yes, it could be dangerous and it could be unexpected but it is not guaranteed to be. You should always try to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: OK, I see!  (*´▽｀)◇ゞ